# Connecting to AI Platform Pipelines using the Kubeflow Pipelines SDK with Python and PyCharm

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

**Using windows 10 and Python 3.9 with PyCharm IDE**

**I am trying to list the pipelines using the following code:**

```
import kfp
client = kfp.Client(host='.......bb92ea05-dot-us-central2.pipelines.googleusercontent.com')
    
client.list_pipelines()
```

**I know the host variable is correct because I copied it from the AI platform Pipeline. I am getting the following problem**:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

**I think that the file can't be found since the program can't connect to the GCP's AI PLatform Pipeline.**

**I have installed Kubeflow Pipeline SDK by doing the following commands in Pycharm terminal:**

- conda create --name mlpipeline python=3.7
- conda activate mlpipeline
- pip3 install kfp --upgrade --user

**When I run:**

```
kfp diagnose_me
```

I get the following command error:

```
Google Cloud SDK is not installed, gcloud, gsutil and kubectl are required for this app to run. Please follow instructions at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install to install the SDK
```

**I have tried**

- Installing Google Cloud SDK and initializing gcloud(**Although when I run a command it says 'Python not found'**)
- Installing kubectl and gsutil with gcloud commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transitioned over to Ubuntu and from there the problem was fixed.

What I did:

- Installed Google Cloud SDK and configured it: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart

  Also install gsutil and kubectl using `gcloud components install component_id` command
- Install KFP SDK: Run the following commands in terminal:

  ```
   apt-get update; apt-get install -y wget bzip2
   wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
   bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

   conda create --name mlpipeline python=3.7   
   conda activate mlpipeline

   pip3 install kfp --upgrade
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem. I fixed it by using Ubuntu OS rather than Windows OS. Use a VM and run Ubuntu in the VM. Ubuntu environment is way easier to set up and manage.